# Unable to open usb interface on Mac, error e000002c5

Tags: macos

I am newbie to Mac development, working on USB communication.
I am referring to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002645-TPXREF101) sample.

When the code executes "USBOpenInterfaceOpen()", error code "e00002c5" is received, which means error while opening for exclusive access.

Solution which I found was to add kext, but I think it requires device specific information such as Vendor Id, Product Id etc to be written in plist file. If this is the case then It is not possible to support multiple devices having different Product Id and Vendor Id.

Is there any way, where I can access the device without using kext ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error you are seeing is saying another driver is currently accessing the device. you can take control from the current owner with the USBDeviceOpenSeize function. If that doesn't work try running your tool as root. If that doesn't work you may have to create a dummy kext that matches the device in question and keeps it available for your user land driver. HTH